# Syntax for LookBehind regex expression

Tags: regex

I need a regex expression which will match 'xmlAttributeReplace=' and the quote following the curly bracket. I then replace these matches with an empty string.

Sample input is

```
<autoUnlockSection xmlAttributeReplace="#{token.variable.sample}" 
     xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
```

I currently have the following

```
xmlAttributeReplace="|(?<=})"
```

My problem is how I'm finding the quote following the curly bracket is incorrect. The look behind should be looking for

1. xmlAttributeReplace=
2. no spaces between the quote and xmlAttributeReplace=

Is there a guru here at regex who might know the correct syntax?

Comment: which programming language are you using?

Comment: Why are you using a regex when it's easier, simpler, more reliable and less error-prone to use an existing XML parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the attribute and the value, you should use:

```
xmlAttributeReplace="[^" ]+"
```

`[^" ]+` simple mean "match characters that are not spaces or quotes". You can be more literal and match `\#\{[\w.]+\}`.

If you want to keep the value but remove the attribute and closing quote, the easiest approach is to capture the value:

```
xmlAttributeReplace="([^" ]+)"
```

and replace with `$1`.

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/tEOJwh/2

Note that you don't require [lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973436/7586) here, nor a regex guru.
Possible caveats, of course, is that you are matching XML with a regex - XML can be complicated, and contain comments, newlines, single quotes, escaped characters, etc.